# Missing type specifier and one more question

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I'm trying to make short chrono declarations

```
#pragma once
#include <chrono>

    class Foo//: public SINGLETON<Foo>
    {
    public:
        using point = std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point;
        using secs  = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>;
        using now   = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    };
```

So that's the whole code.
First issue, this code don't want to compile.
First compile error:

```
 error: 'duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>' in namespace 'std::chrono' does not name a type
  using time_secs  = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>;
```

Second error;

```
error: expected type-specifier
  using time_now   = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
```

Now a question about usage of those, i want to use them like this;

```
time_point  GetElapsedtTime(){return time_secs(time_now - Another_time_point ); }
```

Can I use them like above?

I'm trying to set time point intro a variable, then to countdown the elapsed time until it reaches 1hour for example, then when 1 hour elapses.. do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`using` (in this context) is the equivalent of `typedef`. You are giving a type a new name.

This one: `using point = std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point;` is fine. `std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point` is a type; you're making a new name.

This one: `using secs  = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>;` is not, because `std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>` is not a type - it is a function.

Similarly, `std::chrono::steady_clock::now();` is not a type. It is a value of type `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>`.

(which is what the "does not name a type" message that the compiler gave you says)